# How to let vim automatically scroll when moving the cursor at the bottom?

Tags: vim

Let's assume I just opened a file in vim with many lines of text/code.

I jump to line 150 with `:150` and then my cursor is down at the bottom of the screen and I may wonder how the next couple of lines look like.

I'd like to know about a setting to let vim's cursor never reach the last 4~6 lines of the screen, instead it should scroll the text upwards.

Is such a setting possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 set scrolloff=6
```

for 6 lines of scroll offset. From the vim help:

```
'scrolloff' 'so'    number  (default 0)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor.
    This will make some context visible around where you are working.  If
    you set it to a very large value (999) the cursor line will always be
    in the middle of the window (except at the start or end of the file or
    when long lines wrap).
    For scrolling horizontally see 'sidescrolloff'.
    NOTE: This option is set to 0 when 'compatible' is set.
```